# How to grab contents of a 'specific' output variable from python process, to a powershell script variable? if the python code has multiple outputs

Tags: python, powershell, process

I was trying to automate the launching of a python code for an application. The code has multiple output variables and I only want to grab a single variable's content of the code to a powershell variable. Can this be done? I am very new to powershell.

I was trying to use System.Diagnostics.Process, but seem to have hit a roadblock. Any clue as to how this can be done?

```py
text=r'Text'
image=r'Path\to\image'
lang = r'lang'
read_Text = r'Text_from_image'

s= SequenceMatcher(None, read_Text,text)
r = round(s.ratio(),3) 
print (r)
```

So, as we can see there are multiple variables storing values. Only the last line is outputting to the stream and is grabbed when I use

```bsh
$stdout = $Process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd().
PS $HOME> $HOME\Time.ps1
65.2252356
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Please have a look at my edited question.